# Phone number issues

Tags: sql, toad

I am trying to write a report and in this report there is a sub query that will pull Phone numbers based on the employee’s network_Id. usually the last 4 digits of the network ID is the same as the last four digits of one of the phone number for the employee. My issue is that if a person has two phone numbers meeting the first criteria - `SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, LENGTH(PHONE_NUMBER)-3, 4) = SUBSTR('DP2543',3, 4) )`,then in error out saying single row sub query returns more than one row. Do you know how i can fix this?
Here is the code for phone_numbers:-

```
Select (DECODE((SELECT distinct  PHONE_NUMBER FROM PER_PHONES 
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 26022
        AND SUBSTR(PHONE_NUMBER, LENGTH(PHONE_NUMBER)-3, 4) = SUBSTR('DP2543',3, 4) ), NULL, (SELECT DISTINCT PHONE_NUMBER FROM PER_PHONES 
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID =  26022  AND PHONE_TYPE = 'H1'),(SELECT DISTINCT PHONE_NUMBER FROM PER_PHONES 
  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID =  26022
        AND rownum=1) )  ) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about which one you pick, add `TOP 1` in your subquery

```
SELECT TOP 1 phone_number FROM [etc, etc...]
```

If you do care, then also end the subquery with `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT TOP 1 phone_number FROM [etc, etc...] ORDER BY phone_number
```

Comment: Top 1 does not seem to work in Toad.I dont care which number is picked if there area two numbers meeting the first criteria.